How do I make these 2 flipcards appear side-by-side?
How do I make these 2 flipping cards side-by-side?  Here is the code and the image. I used the w3 TriIt think to instantly test the output with saving to a github repository. Is it because I should just have made them 2 separate divs with the same style? Is it because I should have added the floats internally? Maybe its because inline-block is being overridden by flex in the div style?
I tried floating the 2nd one to the right using inline, did not make them side-by-side (https://i.sstatic.net/wnr00.png)
Floating 1 to the right and one to the left does not change anything at all, both of them stays at the left.(https://i.sstatic.net/V9T5g.png)
Setting body display to inline-block does not work. (https://i.sstatic.net/o6gXB.png)


body {
  margin: 50px;
}

.card-container {
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.front {
  background-color: #3498db;
}

.back {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Sliding Card</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-face front">Front</div>
      <div class="card-face back">Back</div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-face front">Front</div>
        <div class="card-face back">Back</div>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>




Have a look at flexbox or grid instead of trying to use floats/inline-block
